# timespan between now and past datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to calculate how much time elapsed between a datetime and now in minutes.
This is what I have:

```
TimeSpan SinceStatusChange = new TimeSpan();
SinceStatusChange = (double)(DateTime.Now.Date - StatusDateTime).TotalMinutes;
```

Basically, I'm looking to write this conditional statement:

```
if (SinceStatusChange is greater than 180 minutes)
```

How do I write the line "SinceStatusChange = " so I can later test if the value is greater than 180?

Thanks.

Comment: the (double) is underlined saying can't convert 'double' to TimeSpan and when I remove (double) it still gives the same message?

Comment: @frenchie: Because a `double` is not a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: TotalMinutes returns a double, you don't need to cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you are trying to assign a `double` to a `TimeSpan` which, for obvious reasons, will not work.  You already have what you want really, just use:

```
// the 'Minutes' property of a TimeSpan object is a double, 
// so the result is a double, not a new TimeSpan object.
double elapsed = (DateTime.Now - StatusDateTime).TotalMinutes;
if( elapsed > 180 )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite simply:

```
if (DateTime.Now - StatusDateTime > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The call of TotalMinutes on a TimeSpan returns a double. Change the signature of SinceStatusChange to double and you can use it like

```
double SinceStatusChange;
SinceStatusChange = (DateTime.Now.Date - StatusDateTime).TotalMinutes;

if (SinceStatusChange > 180)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a more type safe manner, just using `TimeSpan`s:

```
TimeSpan _180mins = new TimeSpan(3,0,0);
var timeDiff = DateTime.Now.Date - StatusDateTime;

if(timeDiff < _180mins)
{
}
```

Comment: An identifier cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the double you're looking for:

```
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(statusDateTime).TotalMinutes > 180)
    {
        //do work.
    }
```